# Any tool/script available to convert c99 style comments // into c style comments /* ..*/ into whole projects?

Tags: c, linux, shell, comments

Any tool/script available to convert `c99` style comments `//` into `c` style comments `/* ..*/` into whole projects?

if i have code like this

```
// printf("stcakoverflow");
```

then it would be converted like

```
 /* printf("stcakoverflow"); */
```

and also

```
int temp // this is temp varialbe
```

converted into

```
int temp /* this is temp varialbe */
```

Comment: Command line tool or embedded into an IDE?

Comment: what about consecutive lines beginning with // ? one /**/ or each line seperate?

Comment: command line tool will be better...because i dont use any IDE

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For a command-line example, try e.g. something like this:

```
echo "int temp; // this is temp variable" | sed 's@//\(.*\)$@/*\1 */@'
```

The above results in

```
int temp; /* this is temp variable */
```

For a real file you could use e.g. `cat` instead of `echo`, it's the piping to `sed` and the `sed` command that does the "magic".

**Edit:** How to do it for lots of files

Something like this maybe:

```
cd /your/source/directory
mkdir converted-files
for f in *.cpp; do
    cat $f | sed 's@//\(.*\)$@/*\1 */@' > converted-files/$f
done
```

Now all converted source files will be in a folder `converted-files`.

Comment: yea thats good...it works for single file...i need to convert whole projects who has lots of file and directory..

Comment: NotePad++ has regex match and replace and you can do it on a batch of files. Its as easy as doing from the command line. You may give a try.

Comment: @PavanManjunath Mr.32 prefers command line tool. Also this is about a linux environment and afaik there is no linux version of notepad++ but I might be wrong on that

Comment: @Mr.32 Added how you can do it for multiple files.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg greats its working..my projects have multiple folder and they are recursive..so is there any way to handle such things?

Comment: Minor nitpick: you can avoid piping `cat` to `sed` with the [`-i` switch](http://joemaller.com/823/quick-note-about-seds-edit-in-place-option/). This allows you to get rid of the loop, replacing it with: `sed -i '.backup' 's@//\(.*\)$@/*\1 */@' *.cpp`. The original files can then be moved elsewhere with `mv *.backup original-files/`.

Comment: @Mr.32 See the comment from Mathew Hall.

Comment: Note that this won't work correctly in all cases - consider `int temp; //** this is a temporary variable **//`

Answer (score 6):

For people happy using an IDE/Editor, using Notepad++(you can run it on Linux too with Wine) regex match and replace you can do it for a bunch of files.

**Find What** :   `//(.*?)$`

**Replace With** : `/\*\1\*/`

[image]

Comment: In Visual Studio Code you can use regex search `// (.*?)\r?$` and replace `/* $1 */`.

Answer (score 4):

> ccmtcnvt - convert C++ comments to C comments

Answer (score 0):

with the help of Joachim Pileborg

i have made this

```
find /path/to/project/ -type f -exec sed -i  's@//\(.*\)$@/*\1 */@' {} \;
```

here it works fine.. but it works in all file.

if you want it  to work it only for .c  and .h file then

```
find /path/to/project/ -name '*.c' -o -name '*.h' -exec sed -i  's@//\(.*\)$@/*\1 */@' {} \;
```

Comment: `find /path/to/project -name '*.c' -o -name '*.h' -exec ...` This means if will find all files ending in `.c` or files ending in `.h`.